# Python import value if module fails

Tags: python, module

I've written a small Python program. It is executed every 15 minutes by running main.py, which simply loads 2 other python scripts as modules.

The problem is what to do when one module fails (for example because of a lost internet connection). One of the modules parses a feed from the internet. If it fails, it has to assume a certain value. The problem is to import this value to main.py.

The module:

```
[...]
feed=feedparser.parse(url)

if not feed.feed:
    # Assume Error
    print("Error")
    Temperature = 20
    print 'Assuming', Temperature, 'degrees C'
    sys.exit()

Temperature = [...]
```

When I cause the module to fail, main.py exits after the module import. How do I fix this?

I think this is caused by calling sys.exit(), but I dont know what else function I should call?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so catch them and retry importing until it works.

Comment: Of course `sys.exit()` will just exit immediately, without an error. If you don't want to do that… what exactly do you want to do instead? If you're just trying to skip over the next bit of code, write an `if`/`else` and put the next bit of code inside the `else`. (Or, better, refactor it into a function and just call it inside the `else`.) But without seeing more of your code (or, better, [a stripped-down version](http://sscce.org)) it's hard to give a more specific recommendation.

Comment: You are using an import-statement as an implicit procedure call.  That is not what modules are for.  Better would to be put the code into a function and call the function.  Also, handle error conditions more gracefully (like not using `sys.exit()`).

Comment: I do not get errors with the current code, other than the print("Error"). The main program just seems to exit after the sys.exit() call in the imported module.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can have it in a `try except` block:

```
try:
    import moduleA
except ImportError,e:
    import moduleB
```

Answer (score 2):

A python import statement is an expression just like any other Python code. You can wrap your module import in a try...except block, like so:

```
import somemodule
try:
  from someothermodule import Temperature
except ImportError,e:
   Temperature = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted is pretty much it.

main.py:

```
from temperature import Temperature
[some code to insert Temperature into SQLite DB]
```

temperature.py:

```
[...]
feed=feedparser.parse(url)

if not feed.feed:
    # Assume Error
    print("Error")
    Temperature = 20
    print 'Assuming', Temperature, 'degrees C'
    sys.exit()

Temperature = [...]
```

Thanks for the answers so far... I guess there is no way to exit the if statement nicely and pass the assumed Temperature value to main.py?